# Easy way to encrypt and decrypt single digit

Tags: php, .net, encryption

I have a column in the database that stores a "rating" column with values from **1 to 9**.

Is there an easy way to encrypt this column, so that it is not readable for people with full DB and SourceCode access?

There should be a way to extract the exact value (not just mach it to as hash),
and the encrypted strings should be different for the same input.

Looking for a generic approach or  PHP/.NET solution.

Comment: 1 byte "encryption" is kinda pointless. it'd boil down to just XORing the value with something else. e.g. `rating_in_db = real_rating ^ user_id` or something.

Comment: adding row_id will help for the random result, but is there a way to hide the values from people with full DB+SourceCode access (a.k.a the developers)?

Comment: however, if they have access to the database and to the source code, the encryption is pointless

Comment: No, there is no way to hide it from developers/ops.

Comment: No. the devs would be able to see the code and figure out how to undo the crypting anyways. There is NOTHING you can do to hide things from devs like that, unless you store the crypt/decrypt keys somewhere they don't have access to. but since the code needs access to those keys, the devs could just put in some extra code to divert the keys anyways. e.g. it's pointless tail-chasing.

Comment: The point about 1 byte encryption aside, the only way to hide if from those with full souce code access, it so handle the encryption/decryption in an externally hosted service (webservice) that does not have its source exposed, but of course developers can just make a request to this service themselves, with the credentials that the app must have access to, so no, you cannot do this

Comment: @MarcB You can store the keys on some trusted environment (another computer in the back office) or in a smart card, HSM, TPM etc. If you change the column type you could just encrypt with any authenticated cipher mode, but because an attacker can compare ciphertext, you need something unique (e.g. a prefixed IV or any ID) to make sure you cannot simply compare ciphertexts. You'll need more space though than one digit.

Answer (score 0):

I've put a [class](https://github.com/peterurk/Cipher) on github some time ago that will do the trick.

It will encrypt your string as you insert it into the database and you will be able to decrypt it as you retrieve the data.

Below is an example on how to use it

```
require 'Cipher.php';

// First init the class by calling the constructor
// Pass your personal key to the constructor as a
// parameter.
$cipher = new Cipher('AvErrySeCretPasSw0rd!1!2!3!');

$text = 'This is the piece of text we are going to encrypt.';

// Now we encrypt the above text
// The returned value will be a base64encoded form of your encrypted 
// string.
$encrypted = $cipher->encrypt($text);
```

And to decrypt:

```
// Pass your personal key to the constructor as a
// parameter.
$cipher = new Cipher('AvErrySeCretPasSw0rd!1!2!3!');
// Now we are going to decrypt it.
$decrypted = $cipher->decrypt($encrypted);
```

Hope this will help

Comment: I think there are standard and way more secure algorithms then yours ;)

Comment: @d.raev I found sha256 secure enough

Comment: so, this is basically hashing your password with sha256 to derive a secret key, and warpping up mcrypts AES/Rijndael implementation ... looks pretty standard to me ...